# Microsoft SQL server. Getting External script execution failed as extensibility environment is not ready yet. CTP1.2 LINUX version

Tags: sql-server, r, linux

We installed the new last week version of Microsoft SQL server CTP 1.2 VNext **Linux** version of Microsoft SQL server.
Everything is working great except for the R-services. Whenever we are trying to run a query with the sp_execute_external_script command in it we get the following error:

```
Msg 39025, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
External script execution failed as extensibility environment is not ready yet. Retry the operation when the server is fully started.
```

We have set the  following settings the correct way

```
sp_configure 'external scripts enabled', 1;  
RECONFIGURE; 
go
```

And rebooted the whole server multiple times.

The errorlog gives the following information:

```
2017-01-26 13:16:26.68 spid16s     Error: 26024, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2017-01-26 13:16:26.68 spid16s     Server failed to listen on 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 0. Error: 0x2726. To proceed, notify your system administrator.
2017-01-26 13:16:26.68 spid16s     Error: 39002, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2017-01-26 13:16:26.68 spid16s     SQL failed to boot extensibility for error code 0x2726.
```

We Googled a lot but can not find anyone with the same problem or with a solution that works for us or is even possible on Linux.

Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server R Services is not yet supported on SQL Server on Linux. This is documented in the release notes here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes